# Wagtail internal link urls arent working properly

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail, wagtail-pageurl

in my rich body text fields, when an internal page is used for a link, the url that gets attached to the a tag is "https//example.com/example", ie it's missing the colon and the link doesnt work. I get the error "https's server ip address could not be found".

any idea why it is doing this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the site record under Sites -> Settings. The hostname field should NOT contain https - i.e. it should be `example.com`, not `https://example.com`.

Comment: I did think about that. I had set it with the https://, so i removed it but no luck. I guess the existing pages are all still using the old host name in their url in the db

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone else has this issue, it seems having more than one site in wagtail caused this. I had the default localhost site still on there, even after switching to a new production site configuration. deleting the localhost site fixed this.

Comment: If there is only one site, then Wagtail will generate local urls to keep things simple (i.e. `<a href="/some/page/">` rather than `<a href="https://example.com/some/page/">`) - this avoids any issues with host records being set incorrectly.